# Mexed function gives very slight difference when performing math

Tags: matlab, precision, mex, floating-point-precision, matlab-coder

So I tried the matrix exponential function using MATLAB's Coder toolkit, and I got it to build. I went on to test to see if the results were reliable and more efficient. While the code was faster, the answer it produced was very slight.

I ran the original function and got an answer of:

```
p =
            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        -0.05            1    -1.25e-07        5e-06            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
     1.25e-07       -5e-06        -0.05            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0        -0.05            1            0            0            0            0            0            0
  -2.0833e-05      0.00125  -5.2083e-11   4.1667e-09            0            0            1         0.05            0     1.25e-07            0            0
     -0.00125         0.05  -4.1667e-09      2.5e-07            0            0            0            1            0        5e-06            0            0
   5.2083e-11  -4.1667e-09  -2.0833e-05      0.00125            0            0            0    -1.25e-07            1         0.05            0            0
   4.1667e-09     -2.5e-07     -0.00125         0.05            0            0            0       -5e-06            0            1            0            0
            0            0            0            0  -2.0833e-05      0.00125            0            0            0            0            1         0.05
            0            0            0            0     -0.00125         0.05            0            0            0            0            0            1
```

And I then ran the mexed version of the function with the same input:

```
p2 =
            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
        -0.05            1    -1.25e-07        5e-06            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
     1.25e-07       -5e-06        -0.05            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            1            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0        -0.05            1            0            0            0            0            0            0
  -2.0833e-05      0.00125  -5.2083e-11   4.1667e-09            0            0            1         0.05            0     1.25e-07            0            0
     -0.00125         0.05  -4.1667e-09      2.5e-07            0            0            0            1            0        5e-06            0            0
   5.2083e-11  -4.1667e-09  -2.0833e-05      0.00125            0            0            0    -1.25e-07            1         0.05            0            0
   4.1667e-09     -2.5e-07     -0.00125         0.05            0            0            0       -5e-06            0            1            0            0
            0            0            0            0  -2.0833e-05      0.00125            0            0            0            0            1         0.05
            0            0            0            0     -0.00125         0.05            0            0            0            0            0            1
```

At first glance, these two matrices are equal, but they are actually VERY SLIGHTLY off:

```
p-p2
ans =
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
  -6.9389e-18            0            0   8.4703e-22            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
  -3.3881e-21  -2.1684e-19  -3.2312e-26   8.2718e-25            0            0            0            0            0    5.294e-23            0            0
  -2.1684e-19            0  -8.2718e-25    5.294e-23            0            0            0            0            0   8.4703e-22            0            0
   6.4623e-27            0  -3.3881e-21   2.1684e-19            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0   6.9389e-18            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
```

Most of the result is equivalent to the original function, but some of it is not. Also, the difference between the two is so small that I cant possibly believe it would be a mathematical error, rather than perhaps a precision error. And the reason I am so concerned with this, is because this does cause issues with the overlaying reason I am using the function.

Is there a reason why the mex function is off by so little, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the obligatory link: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3):

The differences you observe are so little that you can consider the results **actually are the same.**

The way they are computed are different and that is why you do not get **exactly** the same result. Yet the difference is roughly [`machine epsilon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Approximation_using_MATLAB) and is just due to the fact that computers do not work with an infinite precision but with some discrete representation of the numbers.

Comment: Would probably be worth to note that C needs to perform different steps for array calculations than matlab internally, which may explain the difference. Otherwise + 1

Comment: @sobek is there a way to account for this? My program runs this function possibly hundreds of thousands of times to the point where such a slight difference could really make a difference.

Comment: Do not worry, it won't :)

Comment: you should not be comparing floating-point numbers with equality, but you should check that the absolute/relative difference is smaller than some acceptable tolerance... If your application does actually care about round-off error of that magnitude, then you should probably consider an [arbitrary-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library.

Comment: It's not just that they're different, but both will be different from the "real" answer. The Matlab answer is not more correct than the mex-ed answer. If errors that small really make a difference, you should think about trying to change your algorithm to improve the conditioning. Without using some kind of arbitrary precision methods, you wont ever be able to to get less error.